# How to save array session from a shopping php website in mysql via form hidden value and mysql

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I want to save the orders from the customer but I don't know how to figured with that, I tried to make a hidden form then a second page to take customer dates for billing the orders, but IF I HAVE MORE THEN 1 PRODUCT IS GIVING ME THE name, size for the last PRODUCT (array)

So if I have two products (`product_name` `price` `quanty`)
first value array(`ProductNameFIRST` `150$` `1`)
second value array(`ProductNameSECOND` `200$` `3`) 
ON the form submit page `confirm_comanda.php` is showing me the the array but with the `product_name` value (`ProductNameSECOND`)  only the quanty is good

cart.php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $_SESSION["emptyCart"] = "Yes";
    $emptyCart .= "<h2 align='center'>
COȘUL TAU DE CUMPĂRATURI ESTE GOL</h2><br>
<p>Inca nu ai adaugat produse în cos.<p><br>
<a href='product.php'>Inapoi la campanii</a>";
} else {
    // Start the For Each loop
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        // start select query stmt
        $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, size, details FROM products WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($idSelect, $product_name, $price, $size, $details);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
        while ($stmt->fetch())    {
           $idSelect;
           $product_name; // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
           $price;    
           $size;
           $details;    
        }
        $stmt->free_result();

        // stoop select stmt

        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
                // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
        // Dynamic table row assembly
        $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="100" height="62" border="1" /></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $price . ' RON</td>';
        // How to split a query value into several mutiple rows for a select tag using explode() STAART SIZE
        $myArraySize = explode(' ',  $size);
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><select name="size">';
        foreach($myArraySize as $my_ArraySize)
        {
        $cartOutput .= '<option   value="'.$my_ArraySize.'">'.$my_ArraySize.'</option>';
        }
        $cartOutput .='</select><input name="item_to_adjust_size" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />     
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="changesizes" /> ' . $my_ArraySize . ';';


        $cartOutput .= '</form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />buc
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';
        //STOP SIZE
        //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $pricetotal . ' RON</center></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
```

form hidden value page cart.php

```
$cofirmaComanda = '<form  action="cofirma_comanda.php" method="post">';
            $i=0;
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { //start second forecach
            $i++;
            $cofirmaComanda .='
            <input name="prettotal[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $pricetotal .'">
            <input name="produseID[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
            <input name="produseNume[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">
            <input name="size[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $my_ArraySize .'">
            <input name="cantitate[]"  type="hidden" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] .'">
            <input name="totalCOMANDApret[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $cartTotal .'">';



            } //close second foreach
        $cofirmaComanda .='<input type="submit" name="CofirmaComanda" value="cofirma_comandaTOW"></form>';  
        echo "pret total produs ".$pricetotal."<br>";
        echo "pret nume ".$product_name."<br>";
        echo "ID  ".$item_id."<br>";
        echo "size ".$my_ArraySize."<br>";
        print_r(array($_SESSION['cart_array']));
    } //close else
```

when I type `echo` is write me good the value with `product_name` but when i try to open the confirmation page (`confirm_comanda.php`) 
is writing me wrong...

```
    $countArray = count($_SESSION['cart_array']);// ca stie cate produse se afla in cos
for ($i=0; $i<$countArray; $i++) {
    echo "i= ".$i."<br>";
    $pretTotal = $_POST["prettotal"][$i];
    $PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"][$i];
    $produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"][$i];
    $size = $_POST["size"][$i];
    $cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"][$i];
    $total = $_POST["totalCOMANDApret"][$i];

    echo "nume produs selectat: <strong>".$produseNume."</strong> <br>";
echo $pretTotal." preata total PER PRODUS<br>";
echo $PRODUSE." ID<BR>";
echo $cantitate." cantitate<br>";
echo $size." dimensiune<br>";
echo "total SUMA COMANDA : ".$total." LEI<br>";
$comanda_client = "nume produs selectat: <strong>".$produseNume."</strong> <br>".$pretTotal." preata total PER PRODUSe". $cantitate." cantitate<br>" . $size." dimensiune<br> total SUMA COMANDA : ".$total." LEI<br>";
}
```

and the second form to complete the dates for the custom

```
<form action=""   method="post">
<tr><td>nume: <input name="nume_client" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td>email: <input name="email_client" type="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>telefon: <input name="telefon_client" type="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td>judet: <select name="judet_client">
<option value="Arges">Arges</option>
<option value="Arad">Arad</option>
<option value="Timis">Timis</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>adresa: <input name="adresa_client" type="text"></td></tr>
test <input type="text" size="311"  name="comandaCLIENT" value="<?php echo $comanda_client; ?>">

<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$countArray; $i++) {?>
<input type="text" name="prettotal" value="<?php echo $pretTotal; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produse" value="<?php echo $PRODUSE[$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="produseNume" value=" <?php echo $produseNume[$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cantitate" value=" <?php echo $cantitate; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $size[$i]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="totalComanda" value="<?php echo $total[$i]; ?>"
  <?php }?>
<tr><td><input  type="submit" name="sumbitDateClienti" value="Trimite Comanda"></td><td><input type="button" onClick="location.href='index.php';" value="Inapoi la Cumparaturi"></td></tr>
</form>
```

and the suppose MYSQL INSERT ORDER

```
if(isset($_POST["sumbitDateClienti"])){
$nume = $_POST["nume_client"];
$email = $_POST["email_client"];
$telefon = $_POST["telefon_client"];
$judet = $_POST["judet_client"];
$adresa = $_POST["adresa_client"];

$pretTotalt = $_POST["prettotal"];
echo $pretTotal; 
$PRODUSE = $_POST["produseID"];
$produseNume = $_POST["produseNume"];
$size = $_POST["size"];
$cantitate = $_POST["cantitate"];
$comanda = 'IDprodus: '.$PRODUSE.' / produseNume: '.$produseNume.' / cantitate: '.$cantitate.' / dimensiune: '.$size.' ';
 $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into  comanda (pret_comanda, comanda, nume_comanda, email_comanda, telefon_comanda, judet_comanda, adresa_comanda) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $pretTotalt, $comanda, $nume, $email, $telefon, $judet, $adresa);
    if($stmt->execute())            {
    echo "<strong>succes</strong> pagina a fost creata\n titlu: n<a href='admin_index_istorie.php'><strong>Inapoi la pagina de modificare istorie</strong></a>";

    }
    else {
        echo "eroare";
        }
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Few things to observe here: 1) The way you're using *exploded* array `$myArraySize` in the table/form is wrong. 2) Always add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP scripts to do initial triage on these things. 3) See this line, `<input name="produseID[]"  type="hidden" value="'. $product_name .'">`, you using product name instead of *id* here.

Comment: 2) i have putted - no errors, 1) with what I wrong? 3) i fixed, but it's seams

Comment: Sorry to double post. but noone, can show me the way???